# Why ChangePhoneNumber always returns wrong code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to restore password using UserManager and GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync method.
After trying to confirm that token by ChangePhoneNumberAsync but each time I receive the error about wrong code.

I tried different conditions and each time receiving the same error.

Generating token

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, model.Username);
```

Confirming token

```
var verified = await _userManager.ChangePhoneNumberAsync(user, model.Phone, model.Token);
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;
                config.Tokens.ChangePhoneNumberTokenProvider = "Phone";
            })
```

Phone and username are the same.

```
 var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Email = $"{_templateCustomerEmail}{(_context.Users.Count() + 1)}@{_appSettings.Domain}",
                DateSignUp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                FullName = model.FullName,
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                PhoneNumber = model.Username,
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = false,
                UserName = model.Username
            };
```

I expected really easy set up of these stuff. Unfortunately faced with kind a dummy issue.
Maybe issue is in method names or something else.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call **SetPhoneNumberAsync** method before **GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync**. this is very important point.

I don't know how is your code.

this works.

```
await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, $"{model.CountryCode}{model.PhoneNumber}");    
var code = await _userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, phoneNumber);
```

this does not work.

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, phoneNumber);
await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, $"{model.CountryCode}{model.PhoneNumber}");
```

Because it is using SecurityStamp for validation so every update query changes it.

Comment: The above is right approach. You cannot validate phone number without setting the phone number first

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.generatechangephonenumbertokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2

`GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` takes a user and the phone number. You're giving it user and username, so when you try to change it (confirm the token), you're trying to match a phone number to a username which doesn't match so it gives an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, phone number is the same as username. Updated issue with code.